# Play action not responding to json posted

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, playframework-2.0

I'm new to play and I am trying to post form data to my Play Action using JQuery. However, I'm getting "expected json" response from Action. I check the HTTP Headers to ensure that the data is being sent and it is so, where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.(Is there a better approach to this)

Script:

```
$(document).ready (function (){
    $("form").submit (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("/save",$(this).serialize(),function (data){
            alert(data);
        });
     });
});
```

Action

```
public static Result save()
{
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if (json == null)
    return ok("expected json");
    else
    {
        String value = json.findPath("video").getTextValue();
        if (value == null)
            return ok("did not find");
        else
            return ok(value) ;
    }
}
```

routes

```
  POST   /save                         controllers.Application.save()
```

Comment: Your are not sending JSON to the server.

Comment: You're sending classic form parameters, not Json. it's a Jquery problem, not related to playframework. Search "jquery serialize form as json" for more details. Or just handle form data in your controller.

Comment: @JulienLafont & dfsq - please, give an answer (not a comment) with sample of form serialization to JSON.

Comment: When typing the edit description I accidentally pressed enter instead of backspace, it should be 'retagged, changed java to JavaScript'. Perhaps you should read the tag wiki of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both: **Julien Lafont** and **dfsq** are right, first: you are not serializing your form to JSON, second, as Julien stated, you don't need to... Using your current JS you can just use `DynamicForm` in your `save` action:

```
public static Result save() {
    DynamicForm df = form().bindFromRequest();

    String value = df.get("video");
    if (value == null || value.trim().equals(""))
        return badRequest("Video param was not sent");

    // do something with the value

    return ok(value);
}
```

BTW, don't use `ok()` for returning responses for wrong requests. You have many options: `badRequest()`, `notFound()`, `TODO`, and wild bunch of other [Results](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0.4/java/play/mvc/Results.html), even raw: `status(int)`, so you can read the status in jQuery without passing any additional reasons of fail.

If you really, really need to serialize form to JSON for any reason, let me know, I'll send you a sample.